# Derivatives of a trace with respect to perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ be symmetric positive-definite $n\times n$ matrices. Let $\{\lambda_i(\mathbf{A})\}$ denote the eigenvalues of $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{\Lambda}_{\mathbf{A}}$ denote the corresponding diagonalizing unitary matrix (if it exists) such that $\mathbf{\Lambda}_{\mathbf{A}}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Lambda}_{\mathbf{A}}=\mathbf{D}_{\mathbf{A}}$ where diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D}_{\mathbf{A}}$ contains $\{\lambda_i(\mathbf{A})\}$.

Let $\mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{X}+a\mathbf{Y}$ where $a>0$ is a scalar.  Clearly, $\mathbf{Z}$ is also symmetric positive-definite. By the usual definition of the application of functions to matrices, $\mathbf{Z}\log \mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{\Lambda}_{\mathbf{Z}}\log(\mathbf{D}_{\mathbf{Z}})\mathbf{\Lambda}_{\mathbf{Z}}^T$, where $\log(\mathbf{D}_{\mathbf{Z}})$ contains logs of diagonal elements. Consequently, trace 
$$T=\operatorname{Tr}[\mathbf{Z}\log \mathbf{Z}]=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i(\mathbf{Z})\log \lambda_i(\mathbf{Z}).$$
I am interested in the derivative of the trace with respect to $a$.  Is it possible to write expressions for $\frac{\partial T}{\partial a}$, $\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial a^2}$, and $\frac{\partial^3 T}{\partial a^3}$ in terms of $a$ and eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i(\mathbf{X})\}$ and  $\{\lambda_i(\mathbf{Y})\}$ of $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ (as well as $\mathbf{\Lambda}_{\mathbf{X}}$ and $\mathbf{\Lambda}_{\mathbf{Y}}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is "yes," but I guess you wanted to see what the expressions would be!

The Matrix Cookbook is your friend for this type of question. http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf
You can use the equations in Section 2.3.

First, by the product rule:
$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial a} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ \frac{\partial \lambda_i(\mathbf{Z})}{\partial a} \log \lambda_i(\mathbf{Z}) + \lambda_i(\mathbf{Z}) \frac{\partial \log \lambda_i(\mathbf{Z})}{\partial a} \right] $$

Next note that
$$ \frac{\partial \log \lambda_i(\mathbf{Z})}{\partial a} =
\frac{1}{\lambda_i(\mathbf{Z})} \frac{\partial \lambda_i(\mathbf{Z})}{\partial a} $$
so the only "tricky" thing is to compute the partial of the eigenvalues with respect to $a$.  That's basically Eqn. 67 in the Matrix Cookbook:
$$ \frac{\partial \lambda_i(\mathbf{Z})}{\partial a} = \mathbf{v_i}^T \frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}}{\partial a} \mathbf{v}_i $$
where $\mathbf{v}_i$ are the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{Z}$, i.e. are columns of $\mathbf{\Lambda}_\mathbf{Z}$.  Finally
$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}}{\partial a} = \mathbf{Y} $$.

You are on your own to combine the terms and to compute the higher derivatives from here. (An exercise for the reader.)

Comment: Thanks -- also, I didn't know about the Matrix Cookbook.  It's very interesting, although it's too bad that they don't have derivations (I suppose that the motivation of the authors was to create something similar to Gradshteyn and Ryzhik book of integrals).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial anwser.

In Section 2.5 of the Matrix Cookbook, there is an unnumbered formula between Eqn 98 and Eqn 99 which yields the derivative for the trace of $any$ matrix function.

A few iterations with that formula should convince you that the $k$-th derivative of your function as
$$
(-1)^k \,{\rm tr}\big(Y^k Z^{1-k}\big)
$$
for $k>1$.

For $k=1,\,$ the result includes a $\log$-term
$$
{\rm tr}\big(Y\log(Z)+Y\big)
$$
The complete answer involves reformulating these results in terms of the eigenvalues.

Comment: This matches what I got using help from @Brick.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer comes years late, but I wanted to provide a thorough and correct response that the other answers are lacking. I'll point to Chapter 3 of [Petz' book](http://math.bme.hu/~petz/matrixPD.pdf) on matrix analysis as a reference.

---

Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and let $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be any differentiable function. We will make use of the *divided differences* of $f$, which are defined as follows. For two values $x,y\in I$, we define the first order divided differences as
$$
f^{[1]}(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} & x\neq y\\
f'(x)& x=y.
\end{array}\right.
$$
We may extend the function $f$ to symmetric matrices whose eigenvalues are contained in $I$ by means of the spectral decomposition. That is, if $A$ is a matrix with spectral decomposition
$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\, v_iv_i^T
$$
with eigenvectors $V_1,\dots,v_n$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in I$, then we define $f(A)$ as
$$
f(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(\lambda_i)\, v_iv_i^T.
$$ 
We may assume without loss of generality that $A$ is diagonal, $A = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\, e_ie_i^T$, where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are the standard basis vectors. Define the $n\times n$ matrix $D$ as the matrix of divided differences of $A$, whose $ij$th entry is defined as 
$$
D_{ij} = f^{[1]}(\lambda_i,\lambda_j).
$$

Let $B$ be any other $n\times n$ symmetric matrix. For all values of $t$ small enough, the eigenvalues of $A+tB$ will also be contained in $I$. Then
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}f(A+tB)\right|_{t=0} = D\circ B
$$
where $D\circ B$ is the entrywise product of $D$ and $B$ with matrix elements $(D\circ B)_{ij} = D_{ij}B_{ij}$. In particular, we find that
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{Tr}(f(A+tB))\right|_{t=0} = \operatorname{Tr}(D\circ B) = \sum_{i=1}^n D_{ii}B_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^n f'(\lambda_i)B_{ii}.
$$
Interestingly, this depends only on the diagonal elements of $B$ (where we have assumed that $A$ is diagonal).

Higher-order derivtaives of this function may be taken assuming that the higher-order derivatives of $f$ exist. See for example Theorem 3.25 [here](http://math.bme.hu/~petz/matrixPD.pdf) (or section X.4 of Bhatia's book on [Matrix Analysis](https://books.google.ca/books?id=F4hRy1F1M6QC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

---

In your question, you have chosen the function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=x\log x$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$. In this case, $f'(x)=1+\log(x)$ and 
$$
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{Tr}(f(A+tB))\right|_{t=0} = \operatorname{Tr}(D\circ B) = \sum_{i=1}^n D_{ii}B_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^n (1+\log\lambda_i)B_{ii}.
$$